# Java error try with resource not applicable to variable type

Tags: java, try-catch

getting error in this line

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:/encryptedfile.des"))
```

error: try with resource not applicable to variable type required:java.lang.Autocloseable,
found:java.io.file.inputstream.can any one tell me the best solution for that error

Comment: Please copy and paste the *exact* error message. I doubt that it includes: `found:java.io.file.inputstream`. Also, please tell us what version of Java you're building against.

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with your environment. Is there a chance that you are somehow using java 7 syntax with older JDK?

Comment: Agree with Jon Skeet. Additionally could you please post larger code fragment? `try(...)` is probably not enough. Send the body of try: `try(...) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely forgot to update the referenced JRE classes on your build path. My bet is that because you aren't using the JDK 7 libraries but rather are still referencing the old libraries. In java 7, you MUST have Autocloseable implemented for all input/output streams. Try to change your referenced classes to the most updated classes possible if you're going to be building against JDK .7.

**Edit:** If you are using Eclipse...

To change this: Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE's and be sure you're pointing to the proper JDK.

Comment: It could very well be related to something else, however this was a fix I had when I switched from Java 6 to Java 7.

Comment: The last line assumes OP uses Eclipse. Even if that's the case, you should point to the JDK, not to the JRE.

Comment: Oh,finally i got it,i was used netbeans IDE 7.0,and its not no longer support jdk7.0 .So i think it might be the problem,because the same program works in netbeans IDE 7.2 without any error.Thank you guys you people saved my time.